# Plink/Putty fail on return

Tags: ssh, port, putty

Any one have any idea why a remote command to a NetApp filer would fail when using Plink/Putty (to execute a command) across 2 networks?

Everything is open both ways (multiple firewalls), but the filer seems to be responding from port 22 to some random port.  So my Windows box on the other side doesn't know to answer because the target port isn't 22.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be a NetApp ONTAP bug.

Not sure what the workaround was, but another engineer remedied the issue.

Will see if I can post the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Question:

What do you seen when from the windows box you open a CMD window and use "telnet" to connect to port 22:

# telnet 10.0.0.47 22
 Trying 10.0.0.47...
 Connected to 10.0.0.47.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3

You should see the "SSH-n.n" banner (might be different version string from the filer than my example above).